# Looping code to search for blank cells and add text in the adjacent column

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I am trying to put code together that automatically applies text to a cell, if the adjacent cell is not empty. My data set is as follows;

[image]

I am looking to populate everything in column A, providing it's adjacent column B cell is not empty. So, I want to A6 to 10 populated with OK. This will change each day, as more items are added to column B. This is the code I prepared;

```
Dim BlankCell As Range
Set BlankCell = Sheets("Pipeline").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1)

Do Until BlankCell = ""

If Not IsEmpty(BlankCell) Then
BlankCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "OK"

End If

Loop
```

The IF statement seems to be working. If I run it on it's own it would populate A6 with OK, but then i'd have to run again for A7, and then A8, A9 and finally A10.

At the moment, the loop is running continuously, but only populating A6. It is not then moving to A7, A8 etc.

Any help is much apprecited.

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't made BlankCell iterate or move to the next cell. you need something like `Set BlankCell = BlankCell.Offset(1)`

Comment: Why code? Doesn't a standard embedded IIF formula work?

Comment: It would, but this will be an accumulative report that I eventually want to pass off and so don't want to have any issues around formula being deleted / not copied etc. I've found a way to add the date into the source reports though, thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Sub Tester()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim AnyData As Integer

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Sheets("Pipeline")

ws.Activate

AnyData = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("B2:B10000"))

If AnyData = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
    Else
    GoTo Continue:
End If
 
Continue:

LastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("A2").Formula = "=IF(B2="""","""",""OK"")"
ws.Range("A2").AutoFill Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
                            
End Sub
```

You could then call the sub when opening the workbook.

In ThisWorkbook add :

[image]